# Secure: true on cookie for forced https

Tags: http, ssl, cookies, https, session-cookies

If my website has HSTS / forced https (i.e. user won't be able to access http version of the website), is there any point in setting `secure: true` for the cookies?

Comment: Just setting `Secure` on the cookie isn't enough, this is why the `__Host-` and `__Secure-` cookie prefixes have been introduced to mitigate against potential MITM attack (where HSTS isn't available; but still worth it in the event that it got disabled or whatever).  More details in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641144/).

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, there is a point. Without `secure: true` a browser would send those cookies along with any non-encrypted HTTP requests to your domain whether or not your domain listens to request or responds to it.

You might not expect your user to workaround HSTS and make a non-HTTPS request once they've visited your website and received a cookie, but they might do it anyway for various reasons including, but not limited to, an attacker who is trying to hijack their session manipulating them into doing so.

Comment: What are some ways an user can workaround HSTS? Use some very old browser or configure some settings in their browser? In that case, there's a chance their browser configuration ignores `secure: true` too?

Comment: @Avery235 I'm mainly thinking of them disabling it in their browser settings, (although old browsers or any uncommon browser that doesn't support HSTS yet is also a consideration); maybe their computer clock is wrong so their browser thinks your cert has expired early and they decide they want to try visiting over HTTP so they temporarily disable HSTS. I don't know of a browser with a setting to send secure cookies over HTTP, but even if there is a chance that is also an option, why would you want to add that risk?

Comment: The downside is that I'm not able to test my production server API with Postman because it's not a https client...

Comment: @Avery235 That doesn't make any sense. Postman works just fine with HTTPS.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiesecure. It seems like it's configured to not send back the cookie when the request protocol is not https.

Comment: That make sense, but why isn't the request protocol HTTPS? Postman can make HTTPS requests.

Comment: The request is HTTPS, but the client isn't. The doc says "If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set." So the client must be a HTTPS website too. I tested this multiple times and confirmed that switching on secure doesn't set the cookie. My server only listens to https.

Comment: The client doesn't matter. When the docs say "access your site over HTTP", they are talking about the request to your server. It's not affected by whether or not you make some insecure HTTP requests to some other servers first.